# Remove the user NFC from Windows login screen

Tags: windows, user-accounts, nfc

I have the Asus Suite III (AS3) and Windows 10. When I installed the AS3, this created a new login option on the login screen: 'NFC is not ready now', but I have not seen anything in the configuration.

I have uninstalled the AS3 and used CCleaner and search a lot about this problem, but I do not find any way to remove this option. The only solution was a format of the PC and reinstall again Windows.

Some idea or solution to avoid the format of the PC.

Comment: NFC is for logging in with NFC devices and probably means your PC has NFC support. Or that was software for NFC included in the Asus Suite that you shouldn't have installed if you don't have NFC or no intention of using it.

Comment: My motherboard has that function and the AS3 give me that possibility, but I want to uninstall or disable that user/option but I have not found the option :S

Comment: Not a user, just an additional login option like fingerprint for existing users. Try reinstalling and not select that option.

Comment: Ok, I have corrected that part of the question. That has more sense. Thx. However, I uninstall only that option of the AS3 and rebooted the PC, and I uninstalled all the AS3 and rebooted and cleaned all with the CCleaner, but that login way continues in the login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution [here](https://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/problem-with-disabling-nfc-login-on-desktop-windows-8-1/19188).

Basically, to disable the option to login using the NFC in the Windows login screen, you have to change one property in the registry of Windows.

1. Open the Windows Registry Editor: Write'regedit' in the option 'Execute' of the Windows menu (maybe the option name do not coincide because I have my Windows in Spanish)
2. Go to: '\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ASUS\ASUS NFC LOGON'
3. Edit the property 'Enabled' and write in it 'Off' instead 'On'
4. Restart PC

Now, you will not have the NFC option that has the appearance of a user.